# Tera Online for Ubuntu

Tags: windows

I just switched over from Windows 7 to Ubuntu and am completly new to how Ubuntu works, is there a walkthrough that i havnt found for properly installing Tera Online for Ubuntu? If not could someone tell me how to get a working Tera game going :)

Answer (score 0):

Open the Ubuntu software centre

Search for PlayOnLinux and install it

Installing it will also install Wine (a compatibility layer capable of running Windows applications) and everything else needed to play your game

Once installed open PlayOnLinux to install your game

A user manual for PlayOnLinux can be found at http://www.playonlinux.com/en/manual.html

Tera Online should be in the games list and easily installed

Comment: ok so when i try and download Tera, it keeps sending a message that says: Error in POL_Wine
Wine seems to have crashed

If your program is running, just ignore this message